# Write a pyspark Dataframe into a snowflake table with equal number of columns and one additional autoIncrement column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a pyspark dataframe having 5 columns that I need to write to Snowflake table having 6 columns, 5 columns are the same as dataframe columns but there is 1 additional autoincrement column in snowflake table.

When I am trying to write this dataframe to snowflake table but it gives an error; as column mismatch because of having a different number of columns in dataframe and Snowflake Table. I have already tried mode = 'append' but that doesn't work.

```
df.write.format(snowflake_source_name) \
            .options(**sfoptions) \
            .option("dbtable", table_name) \
            .mode("append").save()
```

> I expect these 5 columns from dataframe should be inserted into
>   snowflake table and 6th autoincrement snowflake column should be
>   autoincremented for each row inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.option("column_mismatch_behavior", "ignore")` like this:

```
 df.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
    .options(**sfOptions) \
    .option("column_mapping", "name") \
    .option("column_mismatch_behavior", "ignore") \
    .option("dbtable", sfTableName) \
    .mode("append").save()
```

`.option("column_mapping", "name")`  is an additional helpful option which will load columns of your dataframe to the Snowflake table based on matching case-insensitive names, rather than the order of the columns. It's recommended you pair these two together. It should be noted that if you have two separate columns of the same name with different letter-case, it will fail (you should not have this ever though).

Answer (score 0):

Auto Increment columns will be auto-incremented like a Sequence . No need to give in Data frame else there will be a column mismatch. While defining a table in SnowFlake, you must have specified the Sequence in Snowflake DB, that will take care. Rest all looks good with your code.

Comment: Hi @Ankur, Thanks for the response but I am not adding autoincrement column to dataframe. The dataframe has 5 columns only and when I am trying to write it to Snowflake table having 6 columns(5 same dataframe columns + 1 autoincrement column) It gives the column mismatch Error

Comment: Can you share your code or you can find my sample code below , that will help.         Employee = Row("FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "WORKPHONE", "CITY","POSTAL_CODE")
employee1 = Employee('Ankur', 'Srivastava', '1-289-759-3751', 'Fremonts',22030)
departmentWithEmployees1 = Row(employee1)
departmentsWithEmployees_Seq = [departmentWithEmployees1]

Comment: I've actually found out the bug it's because one of the column in Snowflake table is VARIANT and in dataframe it's as String . In Spark there is no way to cast the column to VARIANT. Could you please help if you know anything about it.

Comment: Why you have defined the auto-increment column as Variant in Snowflake . You can drop that table and create a new one with the column as Number.

Comment: That's existing table created by client and I am not sure if I can change the schema

Comment: It will come out as String only. Please check below mappings .https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#from-snowflake-to-spark-sql